# How to implement Autocomplete Feature using Spring Rest MVC service

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

My data is in Hashset in the form of User Defined Object (the Hashset contains the Document object, and it consists of name and id as two properties)

I have to develop a Rest Service when the user enters three characters.
The service will be triggered and that service will search against the HashSet Document object's name property and sends the result.

Please, suggest me some approach

Comment: Trial and error is a great approach. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i am not getting any thought how to iterate each object and search ?My Hashset object contains the around 8000 objects.so looking for best approach

Comment: what is your approach? do you have any code sample even *prototype* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worry about the autocomplete later - you need to write the filter part first.

Options include:

Why a hashset? Use a database (maybe Sqlite). Perform a WHERE query on the substring of data that you enter.

Loop over the entire set and add the partial matches to a collection you can return.

Either way, the REST Service doesn't seem to be your question - it's how to return the results in a sensible / quick way back to the client. In that case, the database is definitely recommended

Answer (score 1):

I sense two questions here:

The first is how to perform the search on the HashSet. While 8000 items is not much, you could optimize slightly. Let's start with:

```
List<Item> getItemsMatchingSearch(final String searchString){
    return mySet.parallelStream().filter((Item i)->i.getName().toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase())).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This will go through the entire set, but on multiple threads. If your autocomplete field however only wants to produce items **starting** with a given string, then you can improve the performance even further. First, sort your `Set` by the name field. You can do this by making your `Item` implement `Comparable`.

```
class Item implements Comparable<Item>{
    /*...*/

   public int compareTo(Item other){
       return this.name.compareToIgnoreCase(other.name);
   }
}
```

Ideally, use a `TreeSet` instead of a `HashSet` to get the items always sorted.

Then, when searching, you can loop something like this:

```
List<Item> getItemsMatchingSearch(final String searchString){
    List<Item> result = new LinkedList<>();
    for(Item i:items){
        if(i.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(searchString)>0){
            break;
        }
        if(i.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(searchString.toLowerCase()){
            result.add(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The second part of the question is related to REST. In Spring MVC, you can implement something like this:

```
@RestController
public class SearchClass{

    @RequestMapping("/path/to/domain")
    public @ResponseBody List<Item> getAutocompleteResult(@RequestParam("search") String searchTerm){
        /*... and here choose your favorite implementation*/
    }
}
```

Note that you will need a serializer, such as `Jackson` on your path to transform `List<Item>` into json (or another form). The above code will resolve requests to `path/to/domain?search=foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all providing the valuable comments

i have found some other way. Using apache solr we can implement autocomplete feature.
There is small change in my design (Yet to implement) i will use the solr sever 
to retrieve all my data and index it .

Using Rest API i will call the solr server by passing the search string. 
in solr sever data is already indexed so i will get the fast search result.

Comment: Elasticsearch is another option